# Cheapest way to connect power, DisplayPort and two USB devices to USB-C port

Tags: usb, display-port, docking-stations, adapter

Essentially I want to have a very simple docking solution for a laptop with a USB-C port, to provide power to the laptop and connect a monitor (with DisplayPort) and two input devices (with USB) to it.

What's the cheapest way to achieve this?  It's okay if the charger is separate from the mini-dock.  The only requirement is that only one cable has to be attached to the laptop.

Comment: @Cfinley My usage of the word "build" was a bit unfortunate, not making my intention clear. I edited the question and exchanged "build" with "have".

Comment: I apologize for misunderstanding your question. I have reopened it.